# Angular1+cordova+ionic project failed to build with the below error "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception."

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic2

I am trying to build an old angular+ionic+cordova project which was working fine since last week.
Now its throwing me below error

> Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':debugCompileClasspath'.

> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1.
> Required by:
> project :
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.pom'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find vali
> d certification path to requested target

I tried to add the certificate inside JRE/security/cacert file by using below command "keytool -import -alias example -keystore  "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_331\lib\security\cacerts" -file rootCertFile.der" and I am getting this "Trust this certificate? [no]:  y
Certificate was added to keystore
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_331\lib\security\cacerts (Access is denied)"

Please help me to build my program which was running fine 5 days back.